# Issue in ScrollTabletoBottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I'm developing a chat app in ios and I have custom tableview and UIView with GrowingTextview and button on the bottom. I would like to move the Tableview to bottom when SendButton is Pressed.But it's not scrolling properly to the bottom.

My Code,

```
    -(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
    {

        CGFloat maxHeight = [JSMessageInputView maxHeight];
        CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, maxHeight)];
        CGFloat textViewContentHeight = size.height;

        // End of textView.contentSize replacement code

        BOOL isShrinking = textViewContentHeight < self.previousTextViewContentHeight;
        CGFloat changeInHeight = textViewContentHeight - self.previousTextViewContentHeight;

        if(!isShrinking && self.previousTextViewContentHeight == maxHeight) {
            changeInHeight = 0;
        }
        else {
            changeInHeight = MIN(changeInHeight, maxHeight - self.previousTextViewContentHeight);
        }

        if(changeInHeight != 0.0f) {
            //        if(!isShrinking)
            //            [self.inputToolBarView adjustTextViewHeightBy:changeInHeight];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                             animations:^{
                                 UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f,
                                                                        0.0f,
                                                                        self.ChatTableView.contentInset.bottom + changeInHeight,
                                                                        0.0f);

                                 self.ChatTableView.contentInset = insets;
                                 self.ChatTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
                                 [self scrollToBottomAnimated:NO];

                                 if(isShrinking) {
                                     // if shrinking the view, animate text view frame BEFORE input view frame
                                     [self.inputToolBarView adjustTextViewHeightBy:changeInHeight];
                                 }

                                 CGRect inputViewFrame = self.inputToolBarView.frame;
                                 self.inputToolBarView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                          inputViewFrame.origin.y - changeInHeight,
                                                                          inputViewFrame.size.width,
                                                                          inputViewFrame.size.height + changeInHeight);

                                 if(!isShrinking) {
                                     [self.inputToolBarView adjustTextViewHeightBy:changeInHeight];
                                 }
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             }];


            self.previousTextViewContentHeight = MIN(textViewContentHeight, maxHeight);
        }


        self.inputToolBarView.sendButton.enabled = ([textView.text trimWhitespace].length > 0);

        }
    -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {

        if(!self.previousTextViewContentHeight)
            self.previousTextViewContentHeight = textView.contentSize.height;

        [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];



    }

    - (void)scrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        NSInteger rows = [self.ChatTableView
                          numberOfRowsInSection:0];

        if(rows > 0) {
            [self.ChatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rows - 1 inSection:0]
                                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                          animated:animated];
        }
    }
    - (void)keyboardWillShowHide:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        CGRect keyboardRect = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        double duration = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:[UIView animationOptionsForCurve:curve]
                         animations:^{
                             CGFloat keyboardY = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil].origin.y;

                             CGRect inputViewFrame = self.inputToolBarView.frame;
                             CGFloat inputViewFrameY = keyboardY - inputViewFrame.size.height;

                             // for ipad modal form presentations
                             CGFloat messageViewFrameBottom = self.view.frame.size.height - INPUT_HEIGHT;
                             if(inputViewFrameY > messageViewFrameBottom)
                                 inputViewFrameY = messageViewFrameBottom;

                             self.inputToolBarView.frame = CGRectMake(inputViewFrame.origin.x,
                                                                      inputViewFrameY,
                                                                      inputViewFrame.size.width,
                                                                      inputViewFrame.size.height);

                             UIEdgeInsets insets = self.originalTableViewContentInset;
                             insets.bottom = self.view.frame.size.height - self.inputToolBarView.frame.origin.y - inputViewFrame.size.height;

                             self.ChatTableView.contentInset = insets;
                             self.ChatTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         }];

    }
-(void)sendPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString*TextString;
    TextString=_inputToolBarView.textView.text;


    NSString *rawString = [self.inputToolBarView.textView text];
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimmed = [rawString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
    _inputToolBarView.textView.text = trimmed;

    if ([TextString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"Empty");
    }
    else
    {
        if([sharedClass.unmatchcheckStr isEqualToString:@"unMatched"])
        {
            UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Unmatched you",_userName]
                                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",UNMATCH_CHAT_ALERT]
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                       {
                                           sharedClass.unmatchcheckStr=@"";
                                           [[ChatConnectClass sharedManager]deleteUserRecord:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_toUserID]];
                                           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"match" sender:self];
                                       }];
            [alert addAction:okButton];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
        else
        {
            NSDate *currentDateNSDate = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterCurrent = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatterCurrent setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSString *time = [dateFormatterCurrent stringFromDate:currentDateNSDate];
            NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatterCurrent dateFromString:time];

            int random = arc4random() % 10000;
            NSString *messageId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%lu%d",[[MontageUserDefaults getBasicInfo] valueForKey:kMemberId],(unsigned long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]*10.0),random];
            NSLog(@"MSG id Sent : %@",messageId);
            [[ChatConnectClass sharedManager]insertNewMessages:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_toUserID] message:_inputToolBarView.textView.text messageId:messageId date:currentDate isFrom:NO msgStatus:@"Sending"];
            [[ChatConnectClass sharedManager] sendMessage:_inputToolBarView.textView.text  messageId:messageId  To:self.toUserID];
            array_recieveMessage.array = [[ChatConnectClass sharedManager] fetchMessagesUsingUserid:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_toUserID]];
           [self.ChatTableView reloadData];
           [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];
           _inputToolBarView.textView.text=@"";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this can be easily handled if you use TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView class for your tableView

Comment: why should i use this??.When i press the send button..the tableview just scroll to the bottom..i just want to view the last cell fully..

Comment: The reason that you can't see the last cell is because the keyboard is over the top, you're not adjusting the height of the table to take that into account

Comment: I used this..but not working